# How to search by embedded object in a CrudRepository?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Suppose I have an embeddable class, that is embedded in an entity class like below.

```
@Embeddable
public class FullName {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    // constructor, getters, setters, as needed
}

@Entity
public class Account {
    @Embedded
    private FullName fullName;
    // id, other data and methods
}
```

One person can have multiple accounts, hence the full name is not a key for the Account class. What I would like to have, is the following method in a jpa repository

```
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Long> {
    Collection<Account> findAllByFullName(FullName fullName);
}
```

Initially, I thought this would just work, but apparently it's not that simple. I could not get a method like this to work. The only thing I thought might help, was implement an equals method on FullName, saying that a FullName with same first and last name are equal, but this had no effect.

What I ended up doing for the moment is this:

```
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Long> {
    Collection<Account> findAllByFullNameFirstNameAndFullNameLastName(String firstName, String lastName);

    default Collection<Account> findAllByFullName(FullName fullName) {
        return findAllByFullNameFirstNameAndFullNameLastName(fullName.getFirstName(), fullName.getLastName());
    }
}
```

Is there a way for me to avoid creating this intermediary (visible) method?

Comment: Remember that at the end of the day, it is a SQL query that gets executed. Your RDBMS cannot possibly use the Java `equals` method that you provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Example.html) as below,

```
Collection<Account> findAll(Example< Account > account);
```

And then pass it as,

```
FullName fullName = new FullName(fname, lname);

Account acc = new Account();
acc.setFullName(fullName);
Collection<Account> accounts = accountRepository.findAll(Example.of(acc));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This already is a great step forward! In my real-world application, the embedded object has three fields, and I have an entity that has two such embedded fields. This means the method in the repository has a whopping 6 arguments, and the name is too long to show in my IDE. I will definitely try to use this to avoid that 6-argument monster of a method.

Comment: @ErikRijcken please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: I tried this, but sadly it did not do exactly what I wanted. If I have a FullName with only a last name for example, and a null first name, it will simply ignore the first name, instead of searching for an account with first name null and the given last name. I need to be able to support both cases

Comment: You could use `ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching()     
  .withIncludeNullValues();` and Example.of(acc, matcher). I haven't tried it but it should work.

Comment: But in this case, wouldn't it also look for an exact match for null values of other fields in the Account class for example?

Comment: There any many methods in Example, you need to check to the fit for you. e.g. `ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching()
                    .withMatcher("firstName", ExampleMatcher.GenericPropertyMatchers.regex())`

Comment: What I seem to need, is a way to say "includeNullValue" for one specific path. I can't seem to find a matcher that does this, and I'm unsure if this exists...

Comment: In the end, I changed the data such that the default value for first name is an empty string instead of a null string. This way, I was able to use the Example code. I also had to explicitly exclude some boolean fields in the ExampleMatcher to avoid forcing an equals for these fields.